# Use reduce on an object to return a word that doesn't contain a target letter in an array

Tags: javascript, reduce

I would like to use reduce on an object with values as strings. If that value doesn't contain the target letter than push that value into an array.

For example:

```
var animals = {a: 'pig', b: 'pony', c:'possum'};

useReduce(animals, "i"); // returns ['pony', 'possum'];
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm getting an error:

```
var useReduce = function(obj, target) {
  obj.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, key, obj) {
    if (currentValue.indexOf(target) === -1) {
      previousValue.push(currentValue);
    };
  }, []);
  return previousValue;
};
```

Comment: `reduce` is used with arrays, not objects. You will need to iterate using `for(var key in obj) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the object into an array of keys, then you can reduce. Additionally, `previousValue` relies on the previous call's return value. You forgot to return inside the reduce.

```
function useReduce(obj, target) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((previousValue, key) => {
    if (obj[key].indexOf(target) === -1) previousValue.push(key);
    return previousValue;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As those who have commented have suggested, `reduce` is an array method, not an object method.

It looks like you are trying to `filter` the array of objects by certain criteria. Here is one way to accomplish that based on your example using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

This function will return an array of objects *only* if none of the characters in the `name` property match the second argument (in this case, `i`).

```
var animals = [{name: 'pig'}, {name: 'pony'}, {name:'possum'}];

useReduce(animals, 'i');

function useReduce(arr, str) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
    if (obj.name.match(str)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

// returns [{name: 'pony'}, {name:'possum'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answers posted here I just wanted to point out how you can solve this using a functional library, for example with [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) you can do

```
const animals = {a: 'pig', b: 'pony', c:'possum'}
const noLetter = R.curry((letter, target) => {
  return R.compose(R.reject(R.contains(letter)), R.values)(target)
})
noLetter('i', animals)              // ["pony", "possum"]

const noLetterI = noLetter('i')
noLetterI(animals)                  // ["pony", "possum"]
```